# Remove-SPWeb - content database

Tags: 2013, powershell, site-collection, content-database, spweb

Does the command **Remove-SPWeb remove the web also from the content DB?**
I have a site collection with 10 webs, the size is around 100GB, I wish to *remove some webs* and *reduce the size of the content database.*
Is there a better solution instead of Remove-SPWeb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will delete the web from the Database. But you will not get the space back just with this action. Once something removed from the DB it will not reduced by size rather the white space(unused Space) increased.

I think, you have to shrink the database to get the space back(reduce the size of content DB). their is one rule in the health n monitor which will do the shrink for if it says that db having the free space.

[Database has large amounts of unused space (SharePoint 2013)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh564121.aspx)

Comment: Right, I deleted the SPWebs and then shinked the DB